# How to increase SQL parser speed that using TSqlParser?

Tags: c#, parsing, sql-scripts, tsql-parser

In my code, I have several SQL scripts that I want to parse using `TSql130Parser` in order to refactor them. But this process takes a long time - is there a way to increase the speed of this?

Also I have another question that `TSql130Parser` can get bulk as parameter? If it is possible, how can I do it?

This is my method that I use for parsing procedures by passing content of procedure as `query` in method parameter:

```
public string ParseProcedureQuery(string query, out string procedureName)
{
    procedureName= "";

    try
    {
        TSql130Parser parser = new TSql130Parser(true);

        IList<ParseError> errors;

        var fragments = parser.Parse(new System.IO.StringReader(query), out errors);
        var proc = fragments.ScriptTokenStream.Where(x => x.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Proc || x.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Procedure).Select(x => x.Text).FirstOrDefault();

        if (proc == null) 
            return string.Empty;

        var index = fragments.ScriptTokenStream.FindIndex(c => c.Text == proc);
        var name = fragments.ScriptTokenStream
                            .Select((value, ind) => new { value, index = ind })
                            .Where(pair => pair.index > index && pair.value.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.WhiteSpace)
                            .Select((value, ind) => new { value.value.Text, index = ind }).Where(y => y.index < 3).Select(p => p.Text);

        procedureName = string.Join(String.Empty, name);

        var processedQuery = string.Join(" ", fragments.ScriptTokenStream
                                   .Where(x => x.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.MultilineComment)
                                   .Where(x => x.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.SingleLineComment)
                                   .Where(x => x.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.WhiteSpace)
                                   .Select(x => x.Text));
        return processedQuery;
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

Comment: See my comment for another posting this morning : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000984/why-does-this-query-take-a-long-time-to-run#comment128937397_73000984

Comment: What's  your definition of "a long time", and why does it matter?

Comment: @jdweng `TSqlParser` is a client-side parser, it does not use `SqlClient` or connect to a server

Comment: Seems like you could optimize some of this. Remove `proc` and just do `var index = fragments.ScriptTokenStream.FindIndex(x => x.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Proc || x.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Procedure);` Also `var name = fragments.ScriptTokenStream.Skip(index + 1).Where(token => token.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.WhiteSpace).Take(2).Select(p => p.Text);` Try also setting `SqlEngineType.Standalone`

Comment: @IraBaxter I call this method in a loop and this method in sql parser takes time so I want to make this process faster

Comment: now I use parallel.foreach for calling this method but I want to improve it

Comment: And the TSQLParser doesn't offer a feature like "Prepare" (pre-compile a SQL string) like ODBC/JDBC?